# Are interpretations of quantum mechanics useful/necessary?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, soft-question, quantum-interpretations

Is there any benefit for someone to learn about the interpretations of QM if their only goal is practical, for example to program a quantum computer or even just to get a good grade on a test? Suppose someone who is a physicist simply the left the room every time someone broached the topic of Schrödinger's cat, the Copenhagen interpretation, etc; would it necessarily negatively impact their career?

Comment: Opinion-based questions, including those about academic and career choices, are off-topic on PSE.

Comment: @G.Smith I have a hard time seeing this question as opinion-based after so many papers and books on the interpretations of QM trying to establish the experimental constraints (do you remember Bell's inequality?). A part that every Physical theory requires an interpretation for being meaningful, it is interesting that dust has not settled in the case of QM. One should not unduly add *subjective* to the word interpretation.

Comment: @GiorgioP was wondering if someone might mention Bell's inequality. Bell's inequality is one of the most mind-blowing results in physics and likely wouldn't have been investigated by Bell were it not for questions of interpretation. Of course, the result could have been discovered independently without it, but I think I have to admit that considering interpretations could be useful if done judiciously as long as one doesn't go off the deep end, as opposed to just doing the science and letting that speak for itself. Thanks for you answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say that they are useful but not really necessary, though you should study it at one time or another, but how much you want to get into it is up to you.

> practical, for example to program a quantum computer

Quantum computing is not dependent on what interpretation you are inclined to go with. It still relies on the basic mathematical postulates of quantum mechanics.

> or even just to get a good grade on a test?

Occasionally on a test you may get a question on quantum interpretation(s), but usually you will get a set of problems you need to solve (based on the mathematical postulates of quantum mechanics) which are independent of interpretations. The fundamental postulates of quantum mechanics are generally independent of interpretations which concerns themselves with questions like “is quantum mechanics deterministic or random, and the nature of measurement  etc (of course such questions are attempted to be answered  in deterministic interpretations such as pilot-wave theory or t’Hoofts interpretation).

> Suppose someone who is a physicist simply the left the room every time someone broached the topic of Schrodingers' cat, the Copenhagen interpretation, etc; would it necessarily negatively impact their career?

Apart from appearing as antisocial, there is nothing wrong with being inclined to not adhere to any interpretation. If you are concerned with how things happen and not “why”, then in my opinion you are realist, since physics itself is concerned only with “how”. The why, in this case, interpretations, are usually left to philosophers (generally speaking). Interpretations, in my experience, have never been core/compulsory to any quantum mechanics unit (that I can recall) in university.

They are however very interesting to talk about with students/colleagues!

Comment: Although I do sometimes enjoy discussing interpretations, I'm generally more interested in the "how" than they "why"? Occasionally there's a breakthrough like Bell's inequality whose impetus was an interpretive inquiry like the EPR paradox, but that is quite uncommon. The "why" is useful just often enough to be the exception that proves the rule: physics advances by tackling the "how" without worrying "why." So would that make me a realist, or something else?

Comment: Certainly a realist imo. Can I ask what led you to post your original question?

Comment: I had been reading about how string theory and especially multiverse theory (e.g., https://blogs.scientificamerican.com/cross-check/why-string-theory-is-still-not-even-wrong/) had lead physics astray. It made me wonder whether problems like that could be avoided by eschewing any and all philosophical questions on interpreting the meaning of physics. That probably isn't realistic, though. (cont)

Comment: (cont) A certain amount of philosophical consideration is inevitable, and occasionally even leads to new discoveries, as in the case of the EPR paradox controversy leading to practical experiments which confirmed the Bell inequality. If a philosophical conversation can lead to a breakthrough like that, I'm all for it.

Comment: Interesting. Though you speak as though “string theory is wrong“ is a foregone conclusion. It’s still in its infancy and why do you/whomever think it has “led physicists astray”? That is a bald statement. Multiverse theory is not a string theory concept. Multiple dimensions is a string theory thing. This is entirely physical and not dependent on any interpretations, so to speak of strings means you necessarily speak of multiple dimensions. That’s not to say it doesn’t deserve philosophical interpretation or argument - it probably does.

Comment: You're right; I'm probably too biased against string theory. And of course, string theory and multiverse theory are different things. That's string theory's main benefit: it's not multiverse theory! Hugh Everett is a brilliant man. His son is a brilliant musician, founder of the group Eels. But the multiverse thing, I just can't accept that it's science. Unless someone figures out how to test it, which seems impossible, but I'm open minded. It's impossible until someone does it. Sean Carroll won't like this, but until there's a test for it, multiverse theory isn't science.